# How can I install Atta?

Tags: php, mysql, github, xampp

I've already install `XAMPP` and `composer`. My XAMPP is 7.4 and my composer is using composer 1. I'm not yet upgrading to composer v2.

How can I install this project on my computer? The project seems to be located at https://github.com/erleiuat/Atta.

Comment: Either (A) Clone the GitHub repository - try `gh repo clone erleiuat/Atta` or (B) download the ZIP file (Code > download zip) and install manually

Comment: hello @KenLee , thank you for your answer. after i copy do i need to do `composer install` and do `php artisan serve` like that ?

Comment: In my understanding this package (1) does not use composer to install ; and (2) has nothing to do with laravel

Comment: so how i want to run this project in localhost ? sorry i'm asking so much question since this is my first time, i'm only know how to run Laravel @KenLee

Comment: if you put a file known as "hakimy.php" containing the line <?php echo "Hello"; ?> into the htdocs folder of xampp, you can already run it by visiting the link http://localhost/hakimy.php (It is not a must to use laravel framework to build / run PHP applications -- see ? )

Comment: The project's README already explains this under the "General Installation" section. Download the code from Github to XAMPP's `htdocs` folder (if you don't have Git installed, then you can click on the green "Code" button on Github and click "Download ZIP") and then open `http://localhost` in your browser. No further actions are needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Steps to be done:

1. Open git bash or terminal or command prompt on Windows.
2. Change directory to `htdocs`
3. Run command `git clone gh repo clone erleiuat/Atta`
4. In your browser visit: `http://localhost/Atta/index.php`

That should do the work.

Comment: The database must also be set up as a step.

Comment: @JohnHanley so how i want to set up the database ?

Comment: @Hakimy - Did you look at the documentation for that step? **change the settings in include/database.php to match your database installation.**